# App crashes when UITableView clicked second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

```
MyVC* bottle = [[MyVC alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
bottle.title = @"bottle";

if ( water == nil )
    water = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:bottle];
else
    water.contentViewController = bottle;
```

This code runs once....when I click again on `UITableViewCell` my app crashes..
I am unable to figure it Out Why??

ERROR

```
 -[UIPopoverController setContentViewController:animated:] can only be called after the popover has been presented.'
```

**NOTE** When Change my code this to following it works:

```
MyVC* bottle = [[MyVC alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
bottle.title = @"bottle";

if ( water == nil )
    water = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:bottle];
else
    water = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:bottle];
```

But i uses memory as double allocation is present.How can I resolve this

Comment: Whats the error you get? Could you post the crash log?

Comment: what your giving is not enough to solve the problem.
we need the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:
and didSelectRow...

Comment: @CatalinaT. When the app goes in else part then I am getting error and my app crashes...

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a confusion between initialisation, presentation, and content modification of your UIPopoverController.

It is OK to store your popover on an instance variable, to avoid recreating it every time. It doesn't cause any trouble either to set the contentViewController to a new instance of "Bottle" if that "water" exists already.

But your error messages says it all: `-[UIPopoverController setContentViewController:animated:]` : you are trying to change the content of your popover with an *animation*. It means, your popover must already be presented (i.e. visible). For doing so, use one of the two methods starting with `presentPopoverFrom...` *before* changing its content.

In other words, only once your popover is presented, you can animate a change of content. Note also that it makes no sense to animate a change when your popover is not yet presented / visible. Use the setter `.contentViewController =` for that (or the non-animated method).

A note on your edit/note: Writing the same allocation in the two branches of the if/else clause is pointless. And it doesn't cause the system to use twice memory. Because when the compiler sees the second line ("else"...), it first releases the existing instance of the popovercontroller before allocating the new one and making the "water" instance variable point to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push then try this

```
MyVC *Newpage = [[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Newpage animated:YES];
```

If you want too go back from this page i.e pop then use this
You are using wrong code.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in hiding the popover view. Check if presented correctly.

```
if (popover == nil) {

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: MYVC]; 
        popover.delegate = self;

        [self.tablesPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Use delegate methods to check if popover is visible or not.

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // do something now that it's been dismissed
}
```